# Unable to combine rshift and ralt

Tags: autohotkey

The following works:

```
RAlt & w:: Send, {up}
```

The following does not:

```
Rshift & RAlt & ^w:: Send, {ctrl}{up}
```

I get a message that is an invalid hotkey. Is there a way to combine rshift, ralt, and another key?

Answer (score 0):

```
; >+   - right shift
; >!   - right alt
; ^    - ctrl
; vk57 - virtual code "w" key

>+>!^vk57::Send, {ctrl}{up}
```

[More](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).